# Сортировка матрицы по столбцам

Tags: c++, массивы

Помогите переделать код так, чтобы сортировались отрицательные элементы каждого столбца матрицы по возрастанию. Положительные элементы оставить на своих местах. Здесь все наоборот, вроде как.

```
int sortirovka(int **mas1, int m, int n) {
    int temp;

   for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j; k<n; k++)
            {
                if ((mas1[i][j]<mas1[i][k]) && (mas1[i][j]>0))
                {
                    temp = mas1[i][j];
                    mas1[i][j] = mas1[i][k];
                    mas1[i][k] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Sorted matrix: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(3) << mas1[i][j] << setw(3);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int **mas; // указатель на указатель на массив 
    int m, n; // количество строк и столбцов массива 
    cout << "Stroki i stolbci:" << endl;
    cin >> m >> n; // ввод количества строк и столбцов 
    mas = new int*[n]; // выделение памяти под массив указателей 
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        mas[i] = new int[n];
    cout << "Vvedite elementi v massiv:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            //cout <<  i <<  j ;
            while (!(cin >> mas[i][j]))
            {
                cin.clear();
                while (cin.get() != '\n');
                cout << "Nepravelna vvod. Povtoriti.\n";
                //  cout <<  i <<j;
                //cout << "Введите количество строк: ";
            }
            //  cin >> mas[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << setw(4) << mas[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;

    sortirovka(mas, n, m);

    delete[]mas;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У Вас, кстати неверный код. sortirovka(mas, n, m); должно быть sortirovka(mas, m, n); или получите при определенных параметрах вылет за пределы массива (если повезет, то вылет за пределы памяти рограммы, если нет ахинею в программе, но работу)

Answer (score 2):

Вот так я считаю должно быть:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int sortirovka(int **mas1, int m, int n)
{
    int temp;
    // идем по столбцам - у нас их как раз столько, сколько элементов в строке
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
            {
                if ((mas1[j][i] < mas1[k][i]) && (mas1[j][i] < 0) && (mas1[k][i] < 0))
                {
                    temp = mas1[k][i];
                    mas1[k][i] = mas1[j][i];
                    mas1[j][i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Sorted matrix: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(3) << mas1[i][j] << setw(3);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int **mas; // указатель на указатель на массив 
    int m, n; // количество строк и столбцов массива 
    m = 3; n = 6;
    //cout << "Stroki i stolbci:" << endl;
    //cin >> m >> n; // ввод количества строк и столбцов 
    mas = new int*[m]; // выделение памяти под массив указателей 
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        mas[i] = new int[n];
    //cout << "Vvedite elementi v massiv:" << endl;

    mas[0][0] = -3; mas[0][1] =  6; mas[0][2] =  9; mas[0][3] = -11; mas[0][4] = -16; mas[0][5] = -19;
    mas[1][0] = -2; mas[1][1] = -5; mas[1][2] = -8; mas[1][3] = -12; mas[1][4] = -15; mas[1][5] = -18;
    mas[2][0] =  1; mas[2][1] = -4; mas[2][2] = -7; mas[2][3] = -13; mas[2][4] = -14; mas[2][5] = -17;

    //for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    //  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    //      //mas[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    //      //cout <<  i <<  j ;
    //      while (!(cin >> mas[i][j]))
    //      {
    //          cin.clear();
    //          while (cin.get() != '\n');
    //          cout << "Nepravelna vvod. Povtoriti.\n";
    //          //  cout <<  i << j;
    //          //cout << "Введите количество строк: ";
    //      }
    //      //  cin >> mas[i][j];
    //  }
    //}
    cout << "Matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << setw(3) << mas[i][j] << setw(4);
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    sortirovka(mas, m, n);

    delete[]mas;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

И советую на первых парах в таких задачах (что бы не вводить все время руками) использовать

```
srand(time(0));
```

и функцию

```
rand();
```

это сильно облегчает отладку.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно быть аккуратным и внимательным, сначала обдумываем алгоритм, затем объявляем переменные, имеющие смысл. Затем уточнить задачу: по-возрастанию это вверх или вниз? Первым делом определяемся, что столбцы сортируются независимо друг от друга, значит главный цикл по столбцам.

```
for(int stolbindex=0;stolbindex<stolbs;++stolbindex;){ ... }
```

Далее мы выбираем метод сортировки пузырьком. Этот метод предлагает сравнивать числа только один раз, это значит, что элемент из первого цикла должен сравниваться только с теми, что дальше. Результатом прохода второго цикла должно быть нахождения минимального из отрицательных элементов. Не забываем, что сравнивать будет с теми, что снизу, и мы отрицательны.

```
for(int stringindex=0;stringindex<strings;++stringindex){
  if(mas2[stringindex][stolbindex]<0){
    ... }}
```

Третий цикл начинается из того-же столбца, со строк, что ниже второго цикла, и не забываем, что мы должны быть отрицательны.

```
for(int stringindex2=stringindex+1;stringindex2<strings;++stringindex2){
  if(mas2[stringindex2][stolbindex]<0){
    if(mas2[stringindex][stolbindex]>mas2[stringindex2][stolbindex]){
      ... }}}
```

Дальше все условия нашли, значит меняем элементы.

```
temp=mas2[stringindex][stolbindex];
mas2[stringindex][stolbindex]=mas2[stringindex2][stolbindex];
mas2[stringindex2][stolbindex]=temp;
```

Вот так лучше:

```
for(int stolbindex=0;stolbindex<stolbs;++stolbindex;){ 
  for(int stringindex=0;stringindex<strings;++stringindex){
    if(mas2[stringindex][stolbindex]<0){
      for(int stringindex2=stringindex+1;stringindex2<strings;++stringindex2){
        if(mas2[stringindex2][stolbindex]<0){
          if(mas2[stringindex][stolbindex]>mas2[stringindex2][stolbindex]){
            temp=mas2[stringindex][stolbindex];
            mas2[stringindex][stolbindex]=mas2[stringindex2][stolbindex];
            mas2[stringindex2][stolbindex]=temp;}}}}}}
```

P.S. В **main** ... **sortirovka(mas, m, n);**  ...  перепутали аргументы **m** и **n**. Не забудьте поменять местами или переименовать.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ((mas1[i][j]<mas1[i][k]) && (mas1[i][j]>0))
```

Тут знаки поменяйте на противоположные

Comment: этот код в целом работает построчно, а человеку надо по столбцам